# PHP Convert multidimensional array to match format of another

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, explode

I have two arrays, one is generated by using `explode()` on a comma separated string and the other is generated from `result_array()` in Codeigniter.

The results when doing print_r are:

From explode():

```
Array
(
    [0] => keyword
    [1] => test
)
```

From database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => keyword
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test
        )
)
```

I need them to match up so I can use `array_diff()`, what's the best way to get them to match? Is there something other than `result_array()` in CI to get a compatible array?

Comment: `foreach $db_array as ($key => $val) { $db_array[$key] = $db_array[$key]['name']; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new array like this:

```
foreach($fromDatabase as $x)
{
  $arr[] = $x['name'];
}
```

Now, you will have two one dim arrays and you can run array_dif.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array1 as $line) {
   $new_array[] = array('name' => $line);
}
print_r($new_array);
```

That should work for you.